$\sinh(x^n)\le \sinh^n(x), \forall x\in[0,1], n\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}$
I want to prove that:
$\sinh(x^n)\le \sinh^n(x), \forall x\in[0,1], n\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}$
I tried proving this inequality using induction, but I can't prove that the statement is true for $n+1$. Is there any formula determing $\sinh(x^{n+1})$ in terms of  $\sinh(x^{n})$.

Hint: check that $\frac{\sinh t}t$ is increasing on $t>0$.

The derivative of (RHS-LHS) is positive, as on $[0,1]$, $\sinh x \ge x$, and $\cosh x$ is increasing. Cf. the accepted answer here.

Consider the Taylor expansion of $\sinh(x)=x+\tfrac{x^3}{3!}+\tfrac{x^5}{5!}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.
Since we are looking at $x\in[0,1]$, it is clear that $\sinh(x^n)\leq x^n +x^{3n}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tfrac{1}{(2n+1)!}\leq x^n+x^{3n}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \tfrac{1}{n!}=x^n+\big(e-\tfrac{5}{2}\big)x^{3n}<x^n+\tfrac{x^{3n}}{4}$.
On the other hand, $\sinh^n(x)\geq \big(x+\tfrac{x^3}{6}\big)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n-k}\tfrac{x^{3k}}{6^k}\geq x^n+n\tfrac{x^{n+2}}{6}$.
Now, if $n\geq 2$, we have that $\sinh^n(x)\geq x^n+\tfrac{x^{n+2}}{3}\geq x^n+\tfrac{x^{3n}}{4}>\sinh(x^n)$.
The case $n=1$ is trivial.

Going a bit deeper, we can show that
$$
\sinh(z_1 z_2) \leqslant \sinh(z_1) \sinh(z_2)
$$
for all $z_1,z_2 \in [0,1],$ whence the
required result will follow.
To prove the inequality, first observe
that it is true if one of $z_{1,2}$
is equal to $0,$ or to $1.$
Now assume that $a \in (0,1).$ Then
$$
\sinh(ax) \leqslant \sinh(a) \sinh(x)
$$
for all $x \geqslant 0.$ The proof can use the
factorization
$$
\sinh(z) = z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \right),
$$
and it suffices to verify that
$$
1 + \frac{a^2 x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \leqslant \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \right)
$$
for all $n \in \mathbf N^+$ and for all $x \geqslant 0,$
which is a straighforward task; e.g. the derivative of
the difference between the right- and left-hand
side is positive on $(0,+\infty),$ since
$$
0 < -a^2 + \left( 1 + \frac{a^2}{\pi^2 n^2} \right)
$$
due to $a$ being an element of $(0,1).$
